# Split by word not contained in parentheses

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, reactjs

Here is the my string

```
var string = 'Title:(India OR America) OR Keyword:(Education)';
```

After splitting with "OR" it is showing

```
["Title:(India", "America)", "Keyword:(Education)"]
```

But what I need is the below one.

```
["Title:(India OR America)", "Keyword:(Education)"]
```

Could anyone please help on how to split the string to get the required result.

Comment: https://regex101.com/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To achieve this you'll need to use a negative lookahead to only find the `OR` string where it's not contained in parentheses. Try this:

```js
var input = 'Title:(India OR America) OR Keyword:(Education)';
var output = input.split(/(?!\(.*)\s?OR\s?(?![^(]*?\))/g);

console.log(output);
```

Comment: Hi Rory. Yes it worked well. But in some cases I need to split both with AND or OR

var string4 = 'Title:(India OR America) OR Sector:(Education) AND Sector:(Health)';
could you please update the above regex to split with both AND or OR